# HTML5 tags not working

Tags: html, audio, video

```
<audio controls="control">
            <source scr="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg/mp3"/>
 </audio>
```

I use Netbeans 7.2,I have this file called 1.mp3 inside my WEB-INF folder still its not working.Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have set `scr` attribute, try `src` attribute.

```
<source scr="1.mp3" ...>
```

And check mime types for define valid source type.

[MIME Types for Audio Formats](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: none of them seems to be working, 'src' was a typing error.Rather this code worked in my case.                                    <audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer> 
  <source src="1.mp3" />
</audio>